# Deleting rows in grid attribute table not allowed

Tags: arcgis-10.1

I want to delete records in a raster attribute table. The window shows me an error message while deleting record.

> Grid attribute table is blocked from deletion.

I have attached a picture of the error.

[image: Error message]

Comment: That's because its a RAT, the row is a lookup to a value in your raster which is intrinsically linked. You can create a raster without the value with the Con tool https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000 but you can't delete a row.